# How to place views equidistant horizontally in relative layout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

How to place views equidistant horizontally in `relative layout`?

I want to place views in relative layout occupying equal space according to the number of views added, similar to `weight` in `Linear Layout`

**Layout I tried:** (For three views)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--<View
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <View
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/left">

        <View
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/middle"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <View
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Problem with the above layout is that the first two views are like `wrap_content` and the third one occupies all remaining space. How to make each view occupy one-third of horizontal space?

**Note:**
1. Kindly provide solution only in relative layout, not in `linear layout` or `constraint layout`.
2. The solution required should not be nested with `Linear` or other layouts. (Want flat layout)

Comment: Why do you want to do this with `RelativeLayout`? The correct component to use here would be `ConstraintLayout`. Sure, it might be technically possible with RelativeLayout, but it will be dramatically easier with ConstraintLayout.

Comment: @BenP. The layout is part of a complex view which I had initially tried with constraint layout, but couldn't achieve using that.

Comment: Then I'd recommend focusing your efforts on getting ConstraintLayout to work rather than trying to solve this problem with RelativeLayout.

Comment: @BenP. I had been trying that for a few days and I had also posted a question in SO. I couldn't see any further improvement and hence trying this. Can you help me with that? Question link : https://stackoverflow.com/q/56259274/9636037

Comment: Ah, yes, that question looks rather complex as well. For that, I think you'd be better off doing custom drawing rather than trying to build a ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with the relative layout you can do like this, get the the screen width like this.(need to get the pixel value)

```
 private int Screendp(){
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int widthInDP = Math.round(dm.widthPixels / dm.density);
    return widthInDP;
}
```

this is how we can convert `dp` to `px`

```
  public int dpToPx(int dp) {

    float density = this.getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics()
            .density;
    return Math.round((float) dp * density);
}
```

So in your activity set l`layoutparams` for each and every child views like below,

```
parent= findViewById(R.id.parent);
    left= findViewById(R.id.left );
    middle= findViewById(R.id.middle);
    right= findViewById(R.id.right );



    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams leftparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(  dpToPx(64), dpToPx(64));
    leftparams.leftMargin= 0;
    left.setLayoutParams(leftparams);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams middleparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(  dpToPx(64), dpToPx(64));
    middleparams.leftMargin=dpToPx((Screendp()/3));
    middle.setLayoutParams(middleparams);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rightparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(  dpToPx(64), dpToPx(64));
    rightparams.leftMargin=dpToPx((Screendp()/3)*2);
    right.setLayoutParams(rightparams);
```

This is working and i have tried this.

[image]

Comment: I don't get it. You are setting margin as width/3. How will it affect the width? Can you add more info.

Comment: I have change the answer. try this

Comment: @Abhi can you upvote and accept the answer if it was helpful